# Extract sub String from column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Given String;- `"\NA*(0.0001,0.,NA,0.99999983,0.02)  \EVENT=_Schedule185  \WGT=_WEEKS"`

Output = `EVENT=_Schedule185`

Comment: ultimate goal is to detect the pattern. "EVENT=_Schedule185" or "EVENT=_Schedule01" or "EVENT=_Schedule21". As the input string might looks different but it will have "EVENT=_Schedule(number)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use string extract

`df['col'].str.extract('(EVENT=_\S*) ')`

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to get that into a dataframe then you can use this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : [r"\NA*(0.0001,0.,NA,0.99999983,0.02) \EVENT=_Schedule185 \WGT=_WEEKS"]
})

df['Column1'].apply(lambda x : x.split('\\')[2])
```

However, you are doing all this on an escape character so it might be a little tricky depending on how your actual data is structured. This code, however, will produce the desired results.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, how ever my ultimate goal is to detect the pattern. "EVENT=_Schedule185" or "EVENT=_Schedule01" or "EVENT=_Schedule21". As the input string might looks different but it will have "EVENT=_Schedule(number)"